# How can I generate primary key with particular range in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

```
[Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
```

This code generates the primary key with values from 1 and so on and increments by 1. Is there anyway that I can provide start value for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that it's best to use a sequence instead of an IDENTITY column, eg:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("AccountNumbers", schema: "dbo")
        .StartsAt(1000)
        .IncrementsBy(1);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
        .Property(o => o.AccountNumber)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.AccountNumbers");
}
```

[EF Core - Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/sequences).

For IDENTITY you could call [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in a [Custom Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations).